# Problem with input type='file'

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, forms

I am working on getting my website to display nicely in IE7.
IE6 is already done, and also FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera etc...

I am running IE7 in IETester if that makes any difference.

I have a problem with an input type='file' in IE7. The button next to it (browse button) is very short with hardly any width at all. It is as if the button has a width set to 4px or something.

And on top of that, when I click the very small button, nothing happens. A browse window should appear, but nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```
  <td height="30px" align="left" style="vertical-align:top;">
     <input type="file" id="pic_1" name="pic_1">
  </td>
```

I have tested setting the width of both **td** and the **input**, but no luck.

Does anybody know what the problem might be here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a screen shot? How does it work if you put it outside the td?

Comment: Pekka: Same problem outside the entire table... Sorry have no screenshot right now.

Comment: a screen shot would be helpful. Also, why are you posting the table's CSS if the same problem occurs outside the table?

Comment: I will remove that part, tested it AFTER posting the css.

Comment: Maybe it is because I am running IE7 in IETester?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

avoid IETester. Get a copy of expression web superpreview for IE. Its free.

Comment: "IETester" hacks IE in unsupported ways, which breaks UI features implemented in IEFrame. Including this one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was with IETester.

I tested it on a different computer with IE7 and it works just fine.